# Freeware Local Proxy for Proxy Chaining with HTTPAUTH

Tags: windows, proxy, authentication

I am looking for a freeware local proxy to perform proxy-chaining with HTTPAUTH.

To explain my situation:

In my workplace I am forced to keep switching between several internet-connected apps, and thus everytime I have to type in the credentials (or, at least, click on 'OK' to send my previously-saved credential). To make matters more annoying, the proxy login times out every 30 minutes, requiring me to lather-rinse-repeat the whole annoyance.

I'd like to just point them all to a locally installed proxy which will on its own perform the required HTTPAUTH against the corporate proxy.

I've tried [Cntlm](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cntlm/), but it always fail to authenticate (and according to [this thread](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-users/2010-October/230652.html), that is due to the proxy using HTTPAUTH which is not supported by Cntlm)

Any suggestions?

**ETA**: I found [Polipo](https://www.irif.fr/%7Ejch/software/polipo/), but it's kinda wonky on Windows. Especially if I visit a new URL, and the DNS server is a bit slow, then Polipo will simply drop/refuse the connection. And I have to put my password in plaintext. If there's a better suggestion, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

[WinGate](http://www.wingate.com) will do this, and is free for 10 concurrent users.

Just set your browser to use the locally running WinGate proxy, and configure the proxy to connect through your corporate proxy using the supplied username and password.

[image]

It only supports http Basic auth though, so depending on your corporate proxy rules this may not work.  The reason I still suggest this though, is that typically if your browser is set to use a proxy, and the proxy wants NTLM or Negotiate auth, then that would happen silently and you wouldn't be seeing auth popups.

Disclaimer: I work for Qbik who are the authors of WinGate.